# What is the difference between Backronym and Acronym?

Tags: differences, acronyms

Are **Backronym** and **Acronym** same? I don't understand the difference between these two terms.

Comment: _Backronym_ is a portmanteau of _backward_ and _acronym_.

Comment: So _radar_ is a palindracronym, not a backronym?

Comment: @SvenYargs It's a flipnym of *lapal*.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

An acronym is a word formed by the initial letters of other words, such as Nato (North Atlantic Treaty Organisation). Note that this is different to an initialism where the initial letters are spelled out, as in BBC for example.

A backronym is where the word comes first, and the initial letters are made to fit the word. An example is Alex the parrot ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alex_(parrot))) who to date is the only non-human to spontaneously use language and throws doubt on the notion that a large brain is a prerequisite for language. The name Alex was subsequently said to be 'Avian Language Experiment", which then became 'Avian Learning Experiment. As this was decided (or at least stated) after naming the bird, it is a backronym.

Another example would be the USA PATRIOT Act, where :

*The title of the act is a ten-letter backronym (USA PATRIOT) that stands for Uniting and* *Strengthening America by Providing Appropriate Tools Required to Intercept and Obstruct* *Terrorism Act of 2001*

([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patriot_Act))

Comment: Good explanation

Comment: Occasionally, an acronym can be a backronym. For example, the programming language PHP used to stand for “Personal Home Page”. When it began to be used professionally, it was officially rename “PHP: Hypertext Preprocessor” (a recursive backronym)

Comment: @Madlozoz and what's the difference between a backronym and a recursive acronym? It looks like it is the same. I also heard of the term "reverse acronym", it is the same also?

Comment: @baptx recursive here meaning it's self-referential - in this case because the first P in PHP now stands for PHP.

Answer (score 12):

A backronym (Backward acronym or blend of back and acronym) is a term for a word which has been turned into an acronym by inventing an expansion, rather than the other way around. An example given by [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backronym) involves a backronym invented by *NASA* (itself an acronym - a word formed from initial letters of words and pronounced as a word - for the **N**ational **A**eronautics and **S**pace **A**dministration):

> NASA named its ISS treadmill the **C**ombined **O**perational **L**oad-**B**earing **E**xternal **R**esistance **T**readmill (**COLBERT**) after Stephen Colbert. The backronym was a lighthearted compromise in recognition of the comedian's ability to sway NASA's online vote for the naming of an ISS module.

The word *backronym* was the brainchild of Meredith G. Williams, the winner of the November 1983 edition of the Washington Post monthly neologism contest according to [WordSpy](http://wordspy.com/index.php?word=bacronym).

Backronyms are often used for humorous effect as in the example above (COLBERT), but they are also quite commonly used unintentionally. Other backronyms include

> ZIP code: "Zone Improvement Plan" (used to *speed up* mail processing)
>   DARE - Drug Abuse Resistance Education
>   MADD _ Mothers Against Drunk Drivers

humorous/sarcastic backronyms:

> Microsoft’s Bing: "Because It’s Not Google"
>   Ford: "Found On Roadside, Dead"
>   Delta: "Don't Ever Leave The Airport" or "Don't Expect Luggage To Arrive"

Common acronyms include NASA, NATO, laser, radar, modem, ASAP, etc.

Comment: I would only call something a "backronym" if the name is actually *used* as a name prior to the invention of the expansion.  I would suggest that *most* expanded acronyms contain words that were at least partially chosen for purposes of "fitting" a pronounceable word; only if the short name was chosen without regard for the longer expansion would the term "backronym" be applicable.

Answer (score -5):

A "backronym" is a "backward" acronym. It is a word or expression that is formed from an already existing word. An example is "SAD" = (Seasonal Affective Disorder). So, yes, they are different.

Comment: Oh. I thought acronym of SAD is Seasonal Affective Disorder. https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=_SF4VIfjGq_B8gfG0oGoDw&gws_rd=ssl#q=sad+acronym

Comment: This is simply wrong. If you invent Randolph's Amazing Trapeze and decide to call it the Rat, that's an acronym, even though the word "rat" already exists. If you invent a device called the Rat and then later decide that it stands for "Randolph's amazing trapeze", that's a backronym.